# Error formatting and creating partition on SSD in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, format, wipe

After

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Giving this Error:

> Error formatting volume-Error wiping device: Failed to open the device
> '/dev/sdb1' (udisks-error-quark,0)

[image]

How can I solve this problem and get the disk to format properly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of edit, user solved issue.

Comment: Zrn-dev, helping to understand how this site works can help you here. It's perfectly OK to answer your own question: we even encourage it. However, answers should go in the Answers section, not as edits to your question. Doing that allows you to then mark your answer AS the answer, so the site knows your question has been answered and can highlight it as such. Also, images are helpful, but the primary method of communication in this site is text, as there have been cases where images have gone away irretrievably. So use text primarily, and images to illustrate/illuminate alongside that text.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen you could also move the answer down to the answer area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to first unmount the SSD and then go through the above steps again. 
So, simply unmounting the SSD allows the volume format successfully:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb     # unmount
```